# Сортировка в поле Django

Tags: python-3.x, веб-программирование, django

На сайте имеется поле, куда выбираются пользователи, которое задается с помощью `ManyToManyField`.

Вставка происходит путем выбора из выпадающего списка.После вставки, уже вставленные пользователи сортируются по фамилии(свойство наследуемого полем класса, т.е. пользователя).

*Вопрос* : как отключить эту сортировку и сделать так, чтобы пользователи в поле были в том порядке, в котором они туда вставлялись?

Фреймворк - Django.

Comment: По умолчанию Django никак не сортирует выбранные из базы данные. Так что где-то в вашем коде или указан порядок сортировки для модели, или осуществляется выборка с сортировкой, или написан алгоритм сортировки выбранных данных.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо прибегнуть к сортировке. 
Можно сортировать по id или по дате создания записи.